# Modify chart_Series theme

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to change the colours of the bars using the `theme` argument, but I get an error:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY", from=Sys.Date()-500, to=Sys.Date())
chart_Series(SPY)
chart_Series(SPY,theme=chart_theme(dn.col = "cyan"))
# Error in chart_theme(dn.col = "cyan") : unused argument (dn.col = "cyan")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the code. `chart_theme` takes no arguments, so trying `chart_theme(dn.col="cyan")` makes no sense.

```
> args(chart_theme)
function () 
NULL
```

`chart_theme()` returns a list and you want to modify portions of it, so just do that.

```
myTheme <- chart_theme()
myTheme$col$dn.col <- "cyan"
chart_Series(SPY,theme=myTheme)
```